# when a variable is a zombie or not?

Tags: objective-c, crash, runtime, nszombie

I would like to check when a variable is a zombie & when it is not, i have function like this one, where y have to remove from superlayer if it actually exist, sometimes it is removed already, but being a zombie, it is crashing in this point. What should I do in order to check if the variable is a zombie or not at runtime?

```
 if (avPlayerLayer) {
         [avPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];  
 }
```

I have this code to create it:

```
if (!avPlayer) {
        avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:movieURL];
    } else {
        [avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:movieURL]];
        avPlayer.rate = 0.0f;
    }
}
avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
```

Should I do something like this instead?:

```
if (!avPlayer) {
        avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:movieURL];
    } else {
        avPlayer = nil;
        avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:movieURL];
        avPlayer.rate = 0.0f;
    }
}
avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
```

Any help? thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't be having zombies in the first place, use ARC and weak if you must have a situation like that...

Comment: Thank you Richard, but I wouldn't like to change the whole project now, I'll take that in consideration next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set the variable to nil instead, and then check for nil.

Comment: I think the problem comes in when the super layer is removed without him being able to know about it...

Comment: You were right Oscar, I put avPlayerLayer = nil; after [avPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer]; & it didn't crashed again

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a simple inconsistency in your first implementation ---

```
if (!avPlayer) {

    // This sets avPlayer to a retained object reference (retainCount==1)
    avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:movieURL]; 
} else {
    // This sets avPlayer to an autoReleased object reference 
    // which will die as soon as the memory pool is drained next. 
    // You should have retained it before setting, and your problem will be gone.
    [avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:movieURL]];
    avPlayer.rate = 0.0f;
}
```

I would use:

```
[avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:movieURL] retain]];
```

B.T.W, you can not determine the "zombieness" of an object at runtime, because the zombie mechanism is dependent on some system configuration (environment variables etc.) you cannot set on your client's machine. This is a debug-only tool, and not a proper development technique. A Zombie is a bug in your program. Zombies are meant to help you find and eliminate memory-related bugs, that would otherwise be very hard to track.

Comment: Thank you Motti for the explanation about zombies. Good to know